# ExtJS Store rejectChanges Issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am facing an issue, when i call store.rejectChanges() method. I simply add a record to store on client side.

```
store.insert(0, Ext.create(store.model));
```

Now when user cancels action i call,

```
store.rejectChanges()
```

Shouldn't this newly added record be removed from store? Atleast the documentation says that any phantom records will be removed. But it simply resets the record values but the record still remains there.

Comment: Could you check the phantom property of the newly created model ? rejectChanges could remove model only if phantom === true

Comment: Yes, newly added records should be removed because their phantom if true. Check for phantom value. Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/78h
Tested with ExtJs version 4.1.1

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I debugged it and when rejectChanges is called initially, the record's phantom property is true. But internally within rejectChanges method, it resets the value of the record and then calls rec.commit which sets phantom property to false. Then it tries to see if record is phantom it should remove the record. So it doesn't get removed. I am using latest ExtJs 5. But i guess the problem also occured in ExtJS 4.2

Comment: Where to you read the call to rec.commit mehtod in rejectChanges() ?

Comment: It is not direct call. The stack trace is somewhat like this rejectChanges() -> rec.reject() -> me.set(modified, me._rejectOptions) -> me.commit()

Comment: can you reproduce the issue at https://fiddle.sencha.com    and share the link with us?